# How to indicate use_scm_version in setup.cfg?

Tags: python, setuptools

I'm switching from using `setup.py` to `setup.cfg`.
How can I indicate in `setup.cfg` that I want `use_scm_version= True`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved this by adding `pyproject.toml` file with following code, forcing building to be implemented with `setuptools_scm`:

```
# pyproject.toml
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=45", "setuptools_scm[toml]>=6.2"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[tool.setuptools_scm]
version_scheme = "post-release"
```

Answer (score 1):

See the [recommended usage in project.toml](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools-scm/):

```
# project.toml

[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=45", "setuptools_scm[toml]>=6.2"]

[project]
dynamic = ["version"]  # remove any existing version parameter

[tool.setuptools_scm]
```

According to the [setuptools-scm docs](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools-scm/), this is equivalent to supplying `use_scm_version=True` in `setup.py`.